# Ignore a specific file in ack 2.0 to avoid Permission Denied error

Tags: ack

I have a file that causes Ack 2.0 to report a "Permission denied" error, so I've been trying to get it to ignore the file.

I have tried the following in my ackrc

```
--type-set=lockfile:match:/NameOfLockfile/
--type=nolockfile
```

But it still reports the error "Permission denied".  Using the same syntax I have confirmed that I can get it to not search in the given file (yet it must still try to access it since it gets permission denied error)

Answer (score 5):

Just do `--ignore-file=match:/NameOfLockFile/` or `--ignore-file=is:NameOfLockFile`.  You don't need to set a filetype for it.